# How to structure code with many failure points?

Tags: c, return-value

I have a piece of code that can fail at many points.  With each additional action (that can also fail), the readability worsens.  Is there a better way to structure this?  Is there a design pattern for this?

```
int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void) {
  int32_t retcode;

  retcode = DoA();
  if (retcode != 0) return retcode;
  retcode = DoB();
  if (retcode != 0) return retcode;
  retcode = DoC();
  if (retcode != 0) return retcode;
  retcode = DoD();

  return retcode;
}
```

Alternatively (more readable?):

```
int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void) {
  int32_t retcode;

  retcode = DoA();
  if (0 == retcode) {
    retcode = DoB();
    if (0 == retcode) {
      retcode = DoC();
      if (0 == retcode) {
        retcode = DoD();
      }
    }
  }

  return retcode;
}
```

Comment: Depending on if you need `retcode` after the nested `if` statements, you might instead do e.g. `if (0 == DoA()) { ... }`. Unfortunately there is no "right" or "wrong" answer to this question, which is why I voted to close this as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Is there a best practice or article on bubbling up errors?  Handled at lowest level or highest?

Comment: Definitely not the second one. Yuck, that arrow.

Comment: @Quentin I don't like either alternative, not even the one I proposed in my comment, and that together with your comment is exactly why I voted to close this question. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it probably looks much more opinion-based than it really is, but until someone rolls out an exhaustive list of error handling best practices that no crowd will hate on... Yeah.

Answer (score 5):

In C, a SESE (single entry, single exit) pattern with `goto` is usually appropriate:

```
int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void) {
  int32_t retcode;

  retcode = DoA();
  if (retcode != 0) goto exit;
  retcode = DoB();
  if (retcode != 0) goto exit;
  retcode = DoC();
  if (retcode != 0) goto exit;
  retcode = DoD();

exit:
  return retcode;
}
```

By itself, this isn't any different from your first example that has `return` statements after each check.  But once you your code starts allocating resources, the `goto` approach is much cleaner:

```
int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void) {
  int32_t retcode = E_FAIL;
  A* a = NULL;
  B* b = NULL;
  C* c = NULL;

  a = AllocateA();
  if (a == NULL) goto exit;

  b = AllocateB(a);
  if (b == NULL) goto exit;

  c = AllocateC(b);
  if (c == NULL) goto exit;

  retcode = DoSomething(c);

exit:
  free(c);
  free(b);
  free(a);
  return retcode;
}
```

and now you don't have to worry about figuring out what to clean up at every individual exit point.

Despite what many naysayers say about `goto`, when used properly, it is the sanest form of error-handling in C.

Regarding readability from adding additional actions, I think separating actions with whitespace helps a lot.  Or, if you really want compactness, you could consider doing the action and the error check inline:

```
if ((retcode = DoA()) != 0) goto exit;
```

Comment: Except, you know, [goto fail](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

Comment: `do .. while(0)` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397961/significance-of-do-while0 allows you to use `break` instead of `goto exit;`.

Comment: @Jongware I don't see how that's any improvement.  It's still `goto`, just with a different name but packaged in an odd construct.

Comment: Well I agree with that, but this must be regarded a Win for the No-Goto crowd. It also relieves you of the burden of remembering which label to use.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Had that code duplicated `return err` instead of `goto fail`, the problem would have remained exactly the same.  That bug is not really about `goto`, and SESE/`goto` isn't going to be a magical panacea for all problems.

Comment: @jamesdlin Oh, I agree ... And, I do prefer `goto` over SESE, but, #gotofail itself was significant enough to put in a reminder.

Comment: This is the quintessential example of when `goto` is appropriate.  `goto` is only evil in languages that have better ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer something like this when it is simple error checking without the need for elses.

```
int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void) 
{
    int32_t           retcode = DoA();
    if (0 == retcode) retcode = DoB();
    if (0 == retcode) retcode = DoC();
    if (0 == retcode) retcode = DoD();

    return retcode;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That's why other languages have try/catch. Unfortunately, C doesn't have that feature, so your format (I personally prefer the first one) is probably the best way.

You can also take a look at [Try catch statements in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586003/try-catch-statements-in-c).

Answer (score -2):

There is no particular pattern for this but I use the following format for increased readability and to avoid goto statements.

```
#define BREAK_ON_ERROR(ret_val)  { if (0 != ret_val) break; }

int32_t InitializeMyThingy(void)
{
    int32_t ret = 0;

    do{
        ret = DoA(); BREAK_ON_ERROR(ret) ;
        ret = DoB(); BREAK_ON_ERROR(ret) ;
        ret = DoC(); BREAK_ON_ERROR(ret) ;
        ret = DoD(); BREAK_ON_ERROR(ret) ;

        /* 
             Code executed Gracefully.
             Do Successful handling here. 
        */
        return ret;
    }while(0);

    /* 
         Error Occurred.
         Handle Error Here.
    */
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: [jamesdlin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin)'s [goto example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30007860/369450) is much clearer than this. If it (`do {...} while(0)`) looks like a duck (`goto`) and quacks like a duck (`break` to simulate `goto`), then it's a duck (`goto`).