# Generic cleanup attribute for malloced memory

Tags: c, gcc

There is [GCC-specific attribute `cleanup`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html). It might be used like this:

```
#define SCOPED_FILE __attribute__((cleanup(cleanup_file)))

void
cleanup_file(FILE **file) {
    if (*file != NULL) { fclose(*file); }
}
…
FILE *SCOPED_FILE file = fopen(…); // file will be closed at the end of scope.
```

I thought it would be handy to have cleanup function for any `malloc`ed memory. Having to circumvent casting issues, I came up with the following implementation:

```
#define SCOPED_MEM __attribute__((cleanup(cleanup_mem)))

static inline void
cleanup_mem(void *pmem) {
    void *mem = *(void **)pmem;
    free(mem);
}

int main(void) {
    char *SCOPED_MEM str = malloc(20);
    strcpy(str, "pineapple");
    printf("hi, %s\n", str);
    // str will be free'd at the end of scope
}
```

It does work, but smells funny, because I don't directly specify `void **` as parameter type, but rather cast to it.
I wonder, if there are some problems with it that I don't see right now.

Comment: I don't understand the point of `void *mem = *(void **)pmem;`.

Comment: Could you please explain why you would ever want to use this? It's not like it's very hard to just add some tear down code just before the end of your function.

Comment: @Cheatah, it's not so useful in such simple function, but rather in a function with multiple exit points. In that case, you don't need to manually call cleanup function at every point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I cast `void *` to `void **` and dereference it

Comment: @grepcake I understand. But why?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How else would I pass malloced memory to `free`?

Comment: @grepcake Ah, OK, I see what you did here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574933/a-good-and-idiomatic-way-to-use-gcc-and-clang-attribute-cleanup-and-point The second answer agrees with this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194016/discussion-between-grepcake-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 1):

> but smells funny, because I don't directly specify `void **` as parameter type, but rather cast to it.

Casts in C are often code smells, so you should ask yourself: why is the cast necessary?

One's first approach probably would be:

```
static inline void
cleanup_mem(void **pmem) {
    free(*mem);
}
```

But the compiler won't let you implicitly convert `T**` to `void**` because, strictly speaking, [it's not necessarily safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556443/is-casting-to-pointers-to-pointers-to-void-always-safe/16557330#16557330).

Making `cleanup_mem` take a `void*` and internally cast to `void**` doesn't make that conversion any safer.

Comment: So, it's not possible to do what I want? Besides further limiting platform choice.

Comment: @grepcake In practice, the `void**` cast probably should be okay (but your code should verify that `sizeof (T**) == sizeof (void **)` as a precaution), so I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Using a `gcc` extension already limits portability anyway.  Personally I would just write portable code using [a single-entry, single-exit idiom with `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30007860/179715).